# Cutting string in python

Tags: python, slice

I did some search but couldn't find any useful information.

```
s = ['33PM']
```

My aim is to cut 'PM' from `s[0]` and append it as `s[1]`.

Comment: Maybe it make sense to read the Python Tutorial that is available with the standard Python documentation. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) is the introduction to strings, followed by an introduction to lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that uses simple Python code, avoiding the complications of regular expressions. This is designed for when you know that `'PM'` is in the string, and if there is any text in the string after that it will be moved to the second list item together with the `'PM`. This code also assumes that you care only about the first item in the list--any later items will be dropped.

```
s = ['33PM']

string0 = s[0]
loc = string0.find('PM')
s = [string0[:loc], string0[loc:]]
```

If you now print `s` the result is

```
['33', 'PM']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.findall` to extract continuous range of numbers and characters. `\d+` would extract all numbers and `\w+` would extract all character ranges

```
>>> import re 
>>> s = re.findall(r'\d+|\w+', s[0])
>>> s
['33', 'PM']
```

Comment: Can you explain me that? (Thanks for your explanation!)

Comment: And what If I wanted to cut ['123'] as ['1','23'] ?

Comment: On what basis would like to cut '123' as? How would we know if it has to be `['1','23']` or `['12','3']`

Comment: Keep the first character of s[0] and cut the else to the s[1], maybe?

Comment: Would this help? `s=['123']; s=[s[0][0], s[0][1:]]`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you o/